# Importing from module with the same name as executable file in Python

Tags: python, import

I have an executable file, named, for example, `resource.py`. It is disposed in the folder named `resource`. Renaming file or folder is objectionable - it is old product and users accustomed to use such naming. At old version it was under another project, so imports to it sound like `import main_product.resource.<..>`.

Now I need to use imports like `import resource.<..>` and `__import__('resource.<..>', ...)`. Then I try it, I get an expected error, because Python try to import from the file `resource.py` first.

Suggestion solutions:

1. remove path of current folder from `sys.path`:

   - we need an ugly chunk of code at the begin of the file;
   - no relative imports will be available in this folder;
2. put folder path at the end `sys.path` list:

   - bigger chunk of ugly code at the begin of the file;
   - i am not sure that this feature will always work perfect.

Have any usable idea about this?

P.S. Python v2.6, FreeBSD 7.3

Comment: It's not clear from your question what names exactly need to stay unchanged, and why you can't rename the modules but keep the executables the same. Have you considered using "import XXX as resource" , or trying to refactor the modules into a package ?

Comment: **Rename the modules** works a lot better than messing around with these two "solutions"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `imp.find_module()` and `imp.load_module()`

`find_module` lets you specify your own path to search