# Importing a module which have the same name with a system module

Tags: python, django, importerror, pythonpath

My situation is similar to one in [this question...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3389313/257972) The difference is,

In our python/django project, we have a directory called **utils**, which keeps basic functions...

Sometimes, we need to test some modules by running thm from console like

```
python myproject/some_module.py
```

It is all good, until python tries to import something from **our** utils directory...

```
from utils.custom_modules import some_function
ImportError: No module named custom_modules
```

I check my python path, and our project is on the list, each folder under the project file has `__init__.py` files, and when i run **ipython** within project directory... Everything is ok, otherwise, python imports from its own utils directory...

My collegues use the sama method without any problem, but it throws `ImportError` on my environment... What could be the problem that all of us was missing?

UPDATE: My project directory, and each sub-drectory have `__init__.py` file, and i can import other modules from my project without any problem... When i am in a diffrent folder than my procekt and i run ipython, a such import have no problem...

```
from someothermodule.submodule imprort blahblahblah
```

But, when it comes to importing utils, it fails...

UPATE 2: What caused the problem was the utils directory under **django** folder, which is also in the python path...

Comment: Did you try `from .utils.custom_modules import some_function`

Comment: `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package` error...

Comment: Make your django project a package by adding an empty `__init__.py` to it. If you want to do a relative import, you're treating it as a package already, and it's proper to make it one.

Comment: project directory also have a `__init__.py` file, an empty one... But that must be enough for python to treat it like a python directory as far as i know...

Comment: Does the `utils` directory have an `__init__.py`? It needs to be a subpackage too. Every directory of modules is being used as a package and needs to be made one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the [PEP on absolute and relative imports](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision) for the semantics. You probably want

```
from .utils.custom_modules import some_function
```

if you're in a file at the top level of your package.

Edit: This can only be done from inside a package. This is for a good reason -- if you're importing something that is part of your project, then you're already treating it like a Python package, and you should actually make it one. You do this by adding an `__init__.py` file to project directory.

Edit 2: You've completely changed the question. It may be possible to work around the problem, but the correct thing to do is **not refer to your packed the same way as a builtin package**. You either need to rename `utils`, or make it a **subpackage of another package**, so you can refer to it by a non-conflicting name (like `from mydjangoapp.utils.custom_modules import some_function`).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not going to bother telling you to try and make sure you don't name your own modules after the stdlib modules;

If you want to leave the name like this, you'll have to use something like this in everything that imports your own utils module:

```
import sys, imp

utils = sys.modules.get('utils')
if not utils: utils = imp.load_module('utils',*imp.find_module('utils/utils'))
```

However, unless there's a lot of stuff that you'd have to change after renaming it, I'd suggest you rename it.

Comment: This is absolutely the wrong way to do it. This is what relative imports are for.